# 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method

Tags: swift

**Update**: Swift 3 permits `Self` to be used from other types, thanks to [SE-0068 – Expanding Swift Self to class members and value types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0068-universal-self.md).

You can return "Self" from a class function:

```
extension NSObject {
    class func makeOne() -> Self {
        return self()
    }
}
```

So you can do:

```
let set : NSCountedSet = NSCountedSet.makeOne()
```

However, the following two don't compile:

```
extension NSObject {
    class func makeTwo() -> (Self, Self) {
        return (self(), self())
    }

    class func makeMany() -> [Self] {
        return [self(), self(), self(), self(), self()]
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
<REPL>:11:34: error: 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method; did you mean 'NSObject'?
        class func makeTwo() -> (Self, Self) {
                                 ^~~~
                                 NSObject
<REPL>:11:40: error: 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method; did you mean 'NSObject'?
        class func makeTwo() -> (Self, Self) {
                                       ^~~~
                                       NSObject
<REPL>:15:35: error: 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method; did you mean 'NSObject'?
        class func makeMany() -> [Self] {
                                  ^~~~
                                  NSObject
```

Does anyone know of any way to declare that a class function returns multiple instances of the class itself?

Comment: Worth noting that there's no real reason why this shouldn't be possible – under the hood, for a given static `() -> Self` method on a given type `T`, the compiler just generates a `(T.Type) -> T` function. When called, the caller just casts the result to the actual type that the method is called on. The compiler is able to perform the conversion of an array of subclass instances to an array of superclass instances, and a tuple conversion could be trivially done by decomposition. So while it's technically something the compiler *could* do, it just doesn't support it (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, I suspect, is that Self is ambiguous; it means "this class or a subclass, whatever the thing happens to be *at the time we are called*". In other words, Self is polymorphic. But you can't make an array consisting of two different classes, for example. And although the class may permit a certain initializer, we cannot know in advance that its subclass will.

The solution is to use the class name itself. Here's an example for a struct Thing:

```
extension Thing {
    static func makeTwo() -> (Thing, Thing) {
        return (Thing(), Thing())
    }
}
```

Comment: I can understand the `Array` example, but why it doesn't permit a `tuple`?

Comment: @LuisAscorbe Not sure what you're asking. Note that this was from July 2014! The Swift language has changed greatly since then. If you have a new question with regard to how things are now, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @matt any changes to this? I'd love to return `[Self]` from an extension (on NSObject)... [note that I tried to ask the question again but got closed as a dupe: stackoverflow.com/questions/43400022]... thanks!