# instancetype parameters type in closure/callback for subclasses

Tags: swift, closures

Say I have an asynchronous task to grab an array of instances like so:

```
class func fetchListOfInstances(callback: ([MySuperClass])->()) {
    // do long task asynchronously and call the callback
}
```

and this could be used like so:

```
MySubclass.fetchListOfInstances() { myList in // myList inferred as [MySuperClass]
     for whatever in myList {
         let typeIReallyWant = whatever as! MySubclass
         // do stuff here with each instance of typeIReallyWant
     }
}
```

Swift always seems pretty clever about types so I'll be surprised if if there's not a way to do something like this, but I couldn't find anything from a Google search:

```
class func fetchListOfInstances(callback: ([Self])->()) {
    // do long task asynchronously and call the callback
}
```

...

```
MySubclass.fetchListOfInstances() { myList in // myList inferred as [MySubclass]
     for whatever in myList {
         // do stuff here with each instance of whatever
     }
}
```

It may not be possible, but I thought it would be worth an ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ['Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873166/self-is-only-available-in-a-protocol-or-as-the-result-of-a-class-method) and [Use Self as generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506214/use-self-as-generic-type) it seems what you're after is not currently possible. Instead you could use a function, for example:

```
func fetchInstances<T: MySuperClass>(callback: [T] -> Void) {
    // Do long task asynchronously and call the callback.
}
```

At some point in the function above you're probably going to be creating an instance of `T`. In which case you'll need a required initialiser in `MySuperClass`; meaning all subclasses of `MySuperClass` must also implement that initialiser. For example:

```
class MySuperClass {
    required init(arg: String) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can now use `T(arg: "...")` in `fetchInstances` because you **know** `T` implements `init(arg: String)`.

Finally, you would call `fetchInstances`, explicitly stating the type of `myList` so Swift knows what type `T` is.

```
fetchInstances { (myList: [MySubClass]) in
    // ...
}
```