# How to return Collection of Self type?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm

How do I return objects of type `Self` so that a subclass of `Object` calling this function returns the subclass type instead of the `Object` type?

This doesn't work, however if I replace `Self` with `Object`, it works but I don't get the result I'm looking for.

```
public extension Object {

    class func objects() -> Results<Self> {
        return try! Realm().objects(self)
    }

}
```

Comment: U mean `typeof(self)`?

Comment: I believe this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873166/self-is-only-available-in-a-protocol-or-as-the-result-of-a-class-method